# remove line from file in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have file only_file.txt which have content as below.

```
Y:\mydir1\mysubdir1\subsub1\myfile1_myswt1_swt1_20140431.txt
Y:\mydir2\mysubdir2\subsub2\myfile2_myswt2_swt2_20140431.txt
Y:\mydir2\mysubdir2\subsub2\myfile3_ myswt3_swt3_20140431.txt
Y:\mydir3\mysubdir3\subsub3\myfile3 myswt3 swt3 20140431.doc
Y:\mydir1\mysubdir1\subsub1\myfile6 myswt1 swt6 20140431.xls
```

i want to remove all the filename which are having space, and store the output in other file.

can you please help to write in batch, I have some limitations so i have to do it in windows.

Comment: Does the actual path to the filenames have any spaces in it?

Comment: No the actual path is not having any space, but the file present in folder may have space. No space in folder name only space in file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
find /v " " <"only_file.txt" >"file with no spaces.txt"
```